# desired content should show in web search result

Tags: android

I'm new to android app development. I'm making an application which have the search option.
I have designed a search edit text where I can write anything for search, when clicked on search button it will display the google result page.
Suppose I search for tourist places in Delhi, it displayed a complete google search result with google url in new webview. While I want to show only the tourist places of Delhi without any url.

Comment: show your code that's giving you google search result at least.

Answer (score 0):

Use  [Google Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview)  and do your custom search and show result in a list

Answer (score 0):

Use this line in your code:

```
WebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```